# Интервал между начальной и финальной меткой времени

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-notification

Есть у меня в программе функция отключения уведомлений по заданому времени. То есть условие такое, если current hour == 12 отключаю . Мне надо задать время "С" и "По". Чтобы уведомления отключались например с 00:00 и включались в 8:00.

Мне надо сделать условие , когда текущее время в промежутке например в 23:00 - 08:00 или в 13:00 - 19:00, уведомления не приходили.
Застрял на этом. Если ставить промежуток например 13:00 - 19:00 и текущее время попадается в этот промежуток , то все прекрасно работает, уведомления не приходят.. с этим вот условием

```
calendarCurr.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15, Calendar.SECOND);
        calendarFrom.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 13, Calendar.SECOND);
        calendarTo.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 19, Calendar.SECOND);

if (calendarCurr.before(calendarTo) && calendarCurr.after(calendarFrom)) {
            isSleep = true;
        } else{...}
```

А как быть, если промежуток 23:00 - 8:00 ? 23:00 и 8:00 - два разных дня. Как можно проверить оба условия (13:00 - 19:00 и 23:00 и 8:00)?

Comment: Псевдокод: `(Date2 -Date1).second<8*3600 and Date1.hour>22`
Подробнее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java, гугл -> Java datediff

Comment: можно устанавливать интервал в миллисекундах с датами